# Receiving Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery Ajax. I have learnt how to send Ajax requests. My problem is how to prepare a file to be able to send response in return. Say,the url for my Ajax request is process.php, how do I prepare the process.php file so that I can receive a response of datatype html or text. I know my question sounds weird but I'm more concerned with the methods for processing responses as opposed to sending requests. Pls help me with anything that can be useful to me. I'd prefer examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP endpoint will receive the data using e.g. POST (you can use GET if you like).

Then you need to reply in HTML, JSON, or plain text.

In the example below, you send `$.POST` with a `data` value of, say, `{ cmd: 'time' }`.

```
// Read command. No command is equivalent to an empty string.
$cmd = empty($_POST['cmd']) ? '' : $_POST['cmd'];

// Do something with the command.
switch($cmd) {
    case '': // Empty string
        $reply = "You asked nothing";
        break;
    case 'time':
        $reply = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        break;
    default:
        $reply = "You asked a unexpected question";
        break;
}

/* Text */
Header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf8');
die($reply);

/* HTML */
Header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf8');
die($reply); // This should contain valid HTML

/* JSON, used to send structured data */
$reply = array(
    'status' => 'OK',
    'message'=> 'All good',
    'reply'  => $reply,
);
Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
die(json_encode($reply));
```

In the last case, your callback function will receive an object with members status, message and reply:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (!data.status) {
        alert("Unexpected return from AJAX endpoint: " + data);
        return;
    }
    if ('OK' == data.status) {
        alert(data.reply);
        return;
    }
    alert("AJAX signaled error: " + data.message);
}
```